# Is it safe to bindParams without PDO::PARAM?

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

Here is an example query:

```
$sql = $db->prepare("INSERT INTO `accounts` 
    (`id`, `name`, `email`, `phoneNumber`, `country`, `city`, `addrLine1`, `company`, `zipCode`, `sha_pass_hash`, `ClientGroup`, `Newsletter`, `signedIN`) VALUES 
    (NULL, :name, :email, :phoneNumber, :country, :city, :addrLine1, :company, :zipCode, :sha_pass_hash, '1', '1', NOW())");
$sql->bindParam(':name',$name);
$sql->bindParam(':email',$email);
$sql->bindParam(':phoneNumber',$phoneNumber);
$sql->bindParam(':country',$country);
$sql->bindParam(':city',$city);
$sql->bindParam(':addrLine1',$addrLine1);
$sql->bindParam(':company',$company);
$sql->bindParam(':zipCode',$zipCode);
$sql->bindParam(':sha_pass_hash',$sha_pass_hash);
$sql->execute();
```

As you can see when the bindParam is used `PDO::PARAM` like `PDO::PARAM_STR` and `PDO::PARAM_INT` are not set.

My questions after all is:
Is this query vunerable to SQL Injections when `PDO::PARAM` is not set?

Comment: You're not obligated to specify the datatype. If you want you can. It has no effect on security, and only on how the values are converted before being supplied to the statement.

Comment: **WARNING**: Writing your own access control layer is not easy and there are many opportunities to get it severely wrong. Please, do not write your own authentication system when any modern [development framework](http://codegeekz.com/best-php-frameworks-for-developers/) like [Laravel](http://laravel.com/) comes with a robust [authentication system](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/authentication) built-in. At the absolute least follow [recommended security best practices](http://www.phptherightway.com/#security) and **never store passwords with a weak hash like SHA1**.

Comment: Thank you for replying but my main questions is `Is this query vunerable to SQL Injections when PDO::PARAM is not set` i assume you "vote" for Yes it is safe ?

Comment: If you don't define the type `PDO::PARAM_STR` is used (as default). [PDOStatement::bindParam](http://php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.bindparam.php)

Answer (score 1):

That's the right way to do it. The `PARAM` constants are there for convenience so you can cast/convert your data to the appropriate type as necessary if that's required.

Sometimes this is relevant, you may want certain values as integer to avoid errors when inserting non-numerical data into numerical columns, but if you're prepared to catch and report on these errors you'll have no issues here. That may be a better solution than silently mangling data.

Answer (score 1):

In my opinion, it is totally safe to ignore data types. Because the variable is bound as a reference and will only be evaluated at the time that PDOStatement::execute() is called.

And Note that when using PDOStatement::bindParam an integer is changed to a string value upon PDOStatement::execute(). (Tested with MySQL).

So I use following to run query, and this is a part of [scape](https://github.com/narayangt/scape) Framework

```
/** @var string|array $query
 */
public function runQuery($query){
    /** @var \PDOStatement $statement
     */
    $result=NULL;

    $statement=$this->con->prepare(is_array($query)? $query['query']: $query);

    try
    {
        $statement->execute(is_array($query)?$query['param']:null);
        return $statement;
    }
    catch (\Exception $e)
    {
        if($e->errorInfo[1]==1062)
            echo PHP_EOL."Duplicate Entry. Check your unique Entry such as username, ID etc.".PHP_EOL;
        else if ($e->errorInfo[1]==1146)
            echo PHP_EOL."Table ".$this->getName()." Not Found".PHP_EOL;
        else
            echo $e->getCode().": ".$e->getMessage();
        return false;
    }
}
```

in my function call, $query would be either sting of formatted query or array of following format which is dynamically formatted.

```
$query= ["query" => $tmpQ,
         "param" => [$search],
        ]
```

Comment: looks great but it is always recommended to bind param.

Comment: Thank you for you suggestion. but the data I passed on query are validated and formatted beforehand.